# How to use Microsoft Access database with spring boot and spring data

Tags: database, ms-access, jpa, spring-boot, jdbc

Here is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=BD_Name.mdb")
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

and I use jdk7 which contains the driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver but when I start, springBoot return the exception "couldn't load driver".

Comment: The driver is not for Access sun is Oracle entreprise.. The drivers are not the same for each database you have to search and download the good one.

Comment: Tried using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)? That way you won't need the JDBC-ODBC bridge and the ODBC driver.

Comment: @FoxCy. Your comments  are incorrect. Again.

Comment: @AlanHay I'm sorry but I don't use the same Driver for connect my database PostGre or Oracle or Derby etc... That's why I suggest to check the Driver.. And why you say "comments" and "Again" I just put one comment.

Comment: @FoxCy Before Java 8, `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` was a bridge between JDBC and ODBC and allowed you to access a Microsoft Access database through ODBC.

Comment: It sounds like spring boot starts with Java 8. Please check which Java executable is used when starting your application.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need the following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Connecting MS Access with spring boot, use the below following configuration in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/FazalHaroon/Documents/JavaTest/accountsdb.accdb;openExclusive=false;ignoreCase=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
```

this is the example where i insert new data into my MS Access Database, then i use a select query to fetch all the records from the 'Account' table.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NagarroTaskApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
//        template.update("INSERT INTO account(account_type, account_number) VALUES('test', '1233443543')");

        List<Account> accountList = template.query("SELECT ID, account_type, account_number FROM account", new RowMapper<Account>() {
            @Override
            public Account mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return new Account(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("account_type"), rs.getString("account_number"));
            }
        });
        accountList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with.

Happy coding! ‍

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to connect with MS Access, but the driver used is for JDBC.

Change the driver to the following and it should work:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
```